# Text link in Alert View message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to add a text URL Link in an Alert View message?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a text link easily, but you could have one of the buttons of your alert view open a link for you.

In your `-alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method, call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
```

to have a link open in Safari.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with the button is that it cannot fit the text needed "Go to this website" because it sits next to the "OK" button and not above it. I will have to add some text to the message like "click the button below to go the website".